# Family Polymorphism in Scala How it is working

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, traits

Hi I am getting following error in the below code. Can you please explain the reason for this error?

```
Error - - type mismatch;  found   : UpperClassFamily.Mother
required: StandardFamily.M     (which expands to)  StandardFamily.Mother
```

Code:

```
 object testworksheet {

  trait Family {
        type M <: Mother
        type F <: Father
        type C <: Child

        class Father ( val name: String ) {
            def kiss (m:M) =println ( "Showing signs of af fect ion towards " + m.name)
        }
        class Mother ( val name: String )
        class Child ( val name: String ) {
            def askForhelp (m:M) = println ( "Screeaaaaming at " + m.name)
        }
    }

    object UpperClassFamily extends Family {
      type F = Father ; type M = Mother ; type C = PoliteChild

      class Mother (name: String , val lastName : String ) extends super.Mother (name)
      class PoliteChild (name: String ) extends Child (name) {
        override def askForhelp (m:M) = println ( "Asking " + m.name + m. lastName + " for help" )
      }
    }

    object StandardFamily extends Family {
        type F = Father ; type M = Mother ; type C = Child
    }

    def assignFamily ( f : Family ) = ( )

    val father = new StandardFamily.Father("John")
    val upperClassMother = new UpperClassFamily .Mother ( "Dorthea I I I ","test" )
    father.kiss(upperClassMother)  //Error Location
}
```

Comment: In Scala the types of inner classes are path-dependent, so these types are different by design. If you move `Father` and `Mother` out of `Family` then you won't have that problem.

Comment: But UpperClassMother is Still a Mother right? can you be bit more elaborate? or do we have any documentation? - Thank you

Comment: This is exactly the goal of family polymorphism to prevent you from using a member of one family (`upperClassMother`) with a member of another family (`father`).

Comment: `UpperClassFamily.Mother` is not the same as `StandardFamily.Mother`. As @gzm0 says, that's the point.

Comment: the father kiss neighbor's mother which is not allowed by the law (path dependent). the father only allow to kiss the mother in the same family.